# Itunes Connect shows desktop as platform for ipad app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store-connect

Today i noticed that iTunes Connect sales and trends section has a new skin and some new functionality, however it seems that the app (solely for iPad/iPhone) of my company has downloads on a desktop?

[image: ItunesConnectImage]

Does anyone know what "desktop" could mean for iOS apps?

Comment: Shikiju - Just wanted to say I see the same on my itunesconnect reports for my apps! It doesn't make any sense to me either. Even if the user installed it onto their iOS device via their desktop its still an app install on an iPad or iPhone right ?!?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

it is for mac app store applications. since it is a new content on iTunes they are still ironing it out. it will function properly in a short while. like everything else apple does. i actually called the iTunes department for that.

edit:

as apple advisors let me know: that means someone downloaded the app from their desktop. so it seems that consumers have the ability to download the iOS apps from their desktop. ha, good to know.:)

Comment: "someone downloaded the app from their desktop" - onto what? Their iPad or iPhone right?

Comment: @lemonsanver, to itunes then synced it with their device.

Comment: Cool - thanks! I think my brain has understood the concept now :) I also just tried it out - opened up iTunes, searched for an app, downloaded it. I guess if I then synch my device I could use it (I do wonder if it then registers on iTunes connect with "device install" when I do that)

Comment: @Lemonsanver, it does register. Download is a download. Most people choose to search for apps on their desktop since it maybe easier to download although I still prefer my device.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question though, we were curious about that as well today.

Comment: i have a small free iOS app which typically sees 2 or 3 DLs per day, mostly the US, but a couple days ago it had exactly 250 "Desktop" downloads and a handful of iPad downloads from the UK. any guesses ?  I've seen spikes like this for other non-free apps for educational bulk purchases, but not for a free app.

Comment: Generally is the educational purchase. I've seen up to a 1000 on some of my free apps. It's cool if you have ads on your app.

Comment: So is this still valid? I am trying to download my app on a Mac. It is an iPhone app. The app link with Safari states it can only be downloaded on an iPhone and it can't be found in the Mac app store. I am still seeing 50% desktop in App Store Connect Trends.

Comment: macOS Big Sur don't have iTunes

Answer (score 10):

This is a tool that provides information about installs, not usage.  It doesn't really tell you anything about how people are *using* the application.  I would expect "Desktop" to mean that somebody bought the application through iTunes running on a Mac.

Answer (score 8):

By desktop, it simply means on a Mac or PC someone downloaded the app from iTunes (which stores in your iTunes until you connect your device and sync). Sometimes when you are at your computer it's easier to grab something on sale from iTunes even if you don't sync. The app is still flagged as bought, and if the price goes up you don't have to pay anything.
When browsing or grabbing lots of apps, the computer is usually a bit faster to navigate and easier to flip to app reviews and videos.

For us developers it's an irritating category because we don't know if they are getting the app for an iPad, iPhone or iPod touch.