# iTunes Connect App Analytics & Sales and Trends showing different Values

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes, itunes-store

So when I go to on iTunes Connect and then go to Sales and Trends, it shows I have 50k units. I click devices and it shows that 45k are from Desktop, 4k from iPhone and 1k from iPad. Which to me looks really weird. Then I go to App Analytics it says I have 5k downloads, and it is disregarding the 45k from Desktop. My app is not made for Mac. So why is that?

Comment: sounds like a question for apple not stackoverflow

Comment: I've head it is something to do with schools and institutions downloading it in mass numbers

Comment: Report is correct, by desktop it means someone downloaded the app from iTunes and it's synced with phone later. take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858732/itunes-connect-shows-desktop-as-platform-for-ipad-app