# itunesconnect: real download figure? analytics "app units" vs sales & trends' "units"

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, analytics

In itunesconnect, to check app download figure,
App Analytics and Sales & Trends showing two different figure.

e.g.
For same certain period,
*App Analytics:* App Unit = 1729
*Sales & Trends:* Unit = 1.81K

Which is correct?

I saw some other post (e.g.[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908994/itunes-connect-app-analytics-sales-and-trends-showing-different-values)) discussing similar issue.  But the discussion later didn't come up an answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the official definitions (from itunesconnect.apple.com) and you will see that all the numbers can be different:

**Sales & Trends:**

- **Data Guidelines:** Data includes all device types. Sales data is the
  *estimated* total billed to customers. Proceeds is the *estimated* amount you’ll receive.
- **Date and Time:** Data is shown in UTC or PST. A day includes    transactions that happened from 12:00 AM to 11:59 PM for the selected
  time zone.

**App Analytics:**

- **Data Guidelines:** Data includes devices with iOS 8 or tvOS 9, or later.
- **Date and Time:** Days start at 12:00 AM and end at 11:59 PM (UTC).
- **Opt-In:** We only show data from users who have agreed to share their diagnostics and usage information with app developers. In the last 30 days, xx% of all users that installed apps agreed to share their data.
  Diagnostics and usage information may be delayed by up to 72 hours.

**Summary**

Reporting times are the same if you select the right one (!). App Analytics does not include all sales. If your app is available on older devices, it's not included here. Big question here is: What do you want to achieve? Difference between both numbers in your sample is <5%. For whatever calculations you are doing, just use the same source and don't mix & match.

Comment: These two should be the answer: (1) Date & Time, Sales & Trend use local time zone, and App Analytics use UTC, (2) Devices, Sales & Trend includes all devices, App Analytics includes only iOS 8 or 9

Comment: @cck And not iOS versions above?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the 3 different reports (including Financial) use different sets of starting and ending timezones, different starting and ending times and dates, and different reporting systems (audited vs. unaudited vs. estimated). Apple says the monthly Financial reports are the most correct.

Comment: Thx for your reply.
start and ending dates is same. if timezone and times are different, it is really a problem.

and for most month I don't have a Financial report, why? provided that I am the Agent account.

and if my staff only want to get 7 days figure e.g. download figure, monthly financial report don't serve the function.